# How do I do a search filtered by date AND time in SuiteScript 2?

Tags: datetime, filter, netsuite, suitescript2.0

This works, but only filters by date:

```
var dt = format.format({type: format.Type.DATE, value: new Date()});
search.create({ type: "supportcase", filters: [['lastmodifieddate', search.Operator.AFTER, dt]], columns: ["internalid"] }).run().getRange(0, 1000);
```

But this results in UNEXPECTED_ERROR:

```
var dt = format.format({type: format.Type.DATETIME, value: new Date()});
search.create({ type: "supportcase", filters: [['lastmodifieddate', search.Operator.AFTER, dt]], columns: ["internalid"] }).run().getRange(0, 1000);
```

format.Type.DATETIMETZ also causes UNEXPECTED_ERROR.

Date isn’t enough, I need to filter by date AND time.

The search UI allows filtering lastmodifieddate by date and time:
[image]

After several years with NS I shouldn’t be disappointed at how difficult this is, but I am.

Comment: Check in the search UI if that combination of search operator and field support adding a time. Date Last Modified and Date Created allows times while Start Date doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Brian It does, see updated question

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the goofiest things in SS2.

You can't use an NS formatted DATETIME in a date time search. I use this:

```
function toNSSearchableDatetime(date) {
    var formatted = format.format({ value: date, type: format.Type.DATETIMETZ });
    return formatted.replace(/(:\d{2}):\d{1,2}\b/, '$1');
}
```

so then

```
search.create({ type: "supportcase",
  filters: [['lastmodifieddate', search.Operator.AFTER, toNSSearchableDatetime(date)]], 
  columns: ["internalid"] 
}).run().getRange(0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A browser plugin converts a similar search on sales order to the below. Not sure why it uses two dates:

```
var salesorderSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "salesorder",
   filters:
   [
      ["type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
      "AND", 
      ["lastmodifieddate","after","3/30/2021 12:00 am","3/30/2021 2:20 pm"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "lastmodifieddate", label: "Last Modified"})
   ]
});
```